# Build OSGi bundle include dependencies with maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to create an OSGi bundle include dependencies ,I'm using maven-assembly-plugin ,and this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>logstat</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Log Stat Demo</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
            <artifactId>yecht</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>activator.*,service.*,impl.*</Export-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>activator.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>activator.Activator</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When i run maven build ,it created 2 jars file ,one with dependencies and one without

But in the one with dependencies ,the MANIFEST.MF not include OSGi configuration like :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1392281245886
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Built-By: myname
Bundle-Activator: activator.Activator
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: test
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.wiperdog.logstat
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: activator;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0.0",ser
 vice;version="1.0.0",impl;uses:="org.osgi.framework,service";version="1
 .0.0"
Import-Package: org.jruby.embed;version="[1.7,2)",org.jruby.embed.osgi;v
 ersion="[1.7,2)",org.osgi.framework;version="[1.6,2)"
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
```

it's just have some basic jar configuration ,not OSGi bundle:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Main-Class: activator.Activator
```

So ,how do I have to configuration ?

Comment: Well putting you dependencies inside a bundle (while possible if you private package) is certainly not recommended. OSGi is all about modularity. Why do you want to put all your dependencies in the bundle?

Comment: What is the reason why you use assembly plugin? maven-bundle-plugin has embed-dependency feature. With that, you can control, which package should be exported from the embedded dependencies.

Comment: Thanks,I want to putting some dependencies classes because I want to run some ruby script in osgi environment and the script need to using some classes from log4j , so i need to include something like : require "org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent"

Answer (score 14):

This is quite simple, add the following to your configuration:

```
<Embed-Dependency>dependencies</Embed-Dependency>
```

This is basically it.
The complete documentation can be found at [Felix-Maven-Bundle-Plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#_embedding_dependencies)
and more details on how BND works can be found at [aqute](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Format)

Regarding, best practices of including. If it's something that just your application needs and is mostly hidden, embedding those dependencies can be a valid solution.
If you are reusing this stuff you should think of creating a "shaded" bundle